# WordPress comment_reply_link function result is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

There is some code:

```
function venice_comments() {
    ?>
    <div class="element relative">
      <div class="avatar-wrapper">
        <?php echo get_avatar(get_comment_author_email(), '80', '', '', array('class' => 'round')); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-text"><?php comment_text(); ?></div>
      <div class="push20"></div>
      <div class="item-info f12">
        <span class="item-date"><?php printf(esc_html__('%1$s at %2$s', 'venice'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?></span>
        <span class="person"><?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?></span>
        <span><?php edit_comment_link(esc_html__('Edit Comment', 'some_domain')); ?></span>
        <span><?php comment_reply_link(array('reply_text' => esc_html__('Reply Comment', 'some_domain'), 'max-depth' => 5), get_comment_ID(), get_the_ID()); ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="push35"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

This code works good except `comment_reply_link`, because result of this function is empty. What I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing 'max-depth' => 5' from the comment_reply_link as it is not listed inside the arguments list on this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link)

Instead use 'depth' parameter.

Comment: If I add 'depth' instead of 'max-depth' I get "notice: Undefined index: max_depth in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress_check_theme/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 1603"

Comment: also check if comments are not closed!!